# Angular: Error while aot compilation after upgrade to 4.0.0

Tags: angularjs, templates

I just upgraded my app to Angular 4.0.0 final.

After upgrading (and not changing anything else), I get a bunch of errors telling me the `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

The error messages point to plain html markup in my template fall and not to any 'call targets' I could identify.

Problem is in this file: https://github.com/canonn-science/CanonnApi/blob/feature/site-editor/CanonnApi.Frontend/src/app/components/main-sidebar/main-sidebar.component.html

These are the error messages:

`ERROR in ng:///D:/Dev/CanonnApi/CanonnApi.Frontend/src/app/components/main-sidebar/main-sidebar.component.html (15,9): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ng:///D:/Dev/CanonnApi/CanonnApi.Frontend/src/app/components/main-sidebar/main-sidebar.component.html (15,5): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ng:///D:/Dev/CanonnApi/CanonnApi.Frontend/src/app/components/main-sidebar/main-sidebar.component.html (25,7): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ng:///D:/Dev/CanonnApi/CanonnApi.Frontend/src/app/components/main-sidebar/main-sidebar.component.html (30,84): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ng:///D:/Dev/CanonnApi/CanonnApi.Frontend/src/app/components/main-sidebar/main-sidebar.component.html (31,83): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ng:///D:/Dev/CanonnApi/CanonnApi.Frontend/src/app/components/main-sidebar/main-sidebar.component.html (35,7): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ng:///D:/Dev/CanonnApi/CanonnApi.Frontend/src/app/components/main-sidebar/main-sidebar.component.html (40,84): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ng:///D:/Dev/CanonnApi/CanonnApi.Frontend/src/app/components/main-sidebar/main-sidebar.component.html (41,90): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ng:///D:/Dev/CanonnApi/CanonnApi.Frontend/src/app/components/main-sidebar/main-sidebar.component.html (42,84): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ng:///D:/Dev/CanonnApi/CanonnApi.Frontend/src/app/components/main-sidebar/main-sidebar.component.html (46,7): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ng:///D:/Dev/CanonnApi/CanonnApi.Frontend/src/app/components/main-sidebar/main-sidebar.component.html (51,84): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ng:///D:/Dev/CanonnApi/CanonnApi.Frontend/src/app/components/main-sidebar/main-sidebar.component.html (52,88): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ng:///D:/Dev/CanonnApi/CanonnApi.Frontend/src/app/components/main-sidebar/main-sidebar.component.html (53,83): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this because `router.isActive` on the `Router` class takes more than one argument.

According to the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html):

> isActive(url: string|UrlTree, exact: boolean) : boolean

`isActive` takes the url string AND whether to evaluate it as an exact match.

If I may suggest also another way of accomplishing toggling the 'active' class without using `ngClass` everywhere, instead of

```
<li [ngClass]="{ 'active': router.isActive('/basedata/codex') }">
```

There are [built in directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html) to handle this sort of thing:

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot. Also, the alternative for setting the classes looks nicer.